# LaTeX - Set small fontsize for the entire document

Tags: latex

I want to change the font size to small for the entire document. I have searched online. But I am not able to find a reasonable (one line) answer. Is this possible to change the font size of latex document by only one command.? Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, there's a stackexchange website specifically for LaTeX (and TeX): tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: @William, so does that means TeX questions are no longer welcome here??

Comment: @lhf: It depends, to some extent, on the exact nature of the question. For example, things involving "logic" are probably more welcome here that things involving "page layout design" or "which font". That said, the tex.se community has "more concentrated expertise", so you have a better chance of a quick and comprehensive answer over there.

Comment: @lhf: No, it doesn't mean that. It means that "incidentally, there's a stackexchange website for TeX." No dismissal stated or intended. Cheers

Comment: Here's a related question at tex.stackexchange with some informative answers on getting smaller font sizes than 10pt --- http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5339/4239. Thanks for asking this question, I've learned a bit more about TeX, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think either

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
```

where you replace `10` with whatever font point-size you want, or, perhaps less likely,

```
\begin{document}
\small
```

where you replace `\small` with whatever size-command you want, might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think anything less than 10pt will work when passed to the article class.

Comment: Good point! I've never tried to use anything smaller until you just mentioned it. I found a neat question at tex.stackexchange about going smaller, I posted it up in the question comments.

Comment: Thanks William. I checked the question you mention here. That helps.